# How to create a new file inside wwwroot folder in IIS?

Tags: windows, iis, permissions, windows-10

I have enabled IIS on my windows 10 and I'm not able to create new files in wwwroot folder. When I'm on My Documents or any other folder in Windows and I right click I get a lot of options of files to create, but that context menu doesn't appear in folders inside "wwwroot" folder, I just get an option to create new folders, but not new files. I already tried to change its permissions but without success.

How to?

Comment: Can you make a new file (say a text file) from an elevated Powershell prompt?

Comment: I could fix the problem, it was necessary to check some options on permissions window.